# How to read values from input tag when using jwebunit

Tags: jwebunit

I need to read the values from a series of input tags of a html page. 
Can anyone help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can get the value of input tag in a web page when using JWebUnit in the following way..:

> getElementAttributeByXPath("table//tr[2]//td[2]/input[1]","value")

It gives the value of value attribute of input tag.